# Using Windows 10 netsh portproxy to forward to multiple services

Tags: windows, networking, netsh

I'm working on a project where we have several applications on the same VM, running on Pow. In testing, I might hit the first at `ourdomain.dev`, and content on that page that also makes requests to `ourdomain2.dev`. They are served on different ports- let's say `192.168.10.10:3000` and `192.168.10.10:8888` respectively.

I can set up a proxy using netsh to the applications with the following commands:

```
netsh.exe interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=ourdomain.dev listenport=80 connectaddress=192.168.10.10 connectport=3000
netsh.exe interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=ourdomain2.dev listenport=80 connectaddress=192.168.10.10 connectport=8888
```

... however, only the most recently added entry takes precedence- I'm guessing because they both need to listen on port 80?

If I add *only one* of the above, everything will work for that specific service. However, if I add more than one as above, requests going to `ourdomain.dev` would also be sent to `ourdomain2.dev`.

It's possible to accomplish the routing I need by modifying the Win10 hosts file, however I would prefer to directly reference the application VM's IP and port rather than the host machine to make the solution more portable (the VM's IP is static in our environment).

Comment: Names don't exist at the TCP level. You'll need two different public IP addresses if you want to different services on port 80.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping that wasn't the case. Thanks for the info, I didn't realize that- appreciate pointing me in the right direction, so I can read up!